# Android: how remove Facebook's login/dialogFeed after orientation's change

Tags: android, facebook

In my app, I can call a Facebook's login (or Dialogfeed) from a custom DialogFragment.

When I change device's orientation I manually "re-show" the DialogFragment inside onConfigurationChanged():

```
Fragment resultFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Mydialog");
        if (resultFrag != null) {
            DialogImage dialognew = DialogImage.newInstance(user,index,title,url);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(resultFrag).commit();
            dialognew.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Mydialog");

        }
```

I have a problem whith Facebook's login (or Dialogfeed) because the DialogFragment dont remain behind it when I "re-show" it.

What can I do to put/hide the DialogFragment behind the Facebook's login (or Dialogfeed) again?

or how can I remove the Facebook's login (or Dialogfeed) (if it's there)? (It´s a possible solution, the user should relaunch... doesnt matter)

thanks in advance

PD: more code of my app

when my main activity call my DialogFragment:

```
FragmentManager ft = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    DialogImage dialog = DialogImage.newInstance(user,index,title,url);
                    dialog.show(ft, "Mydialog");
```

LogginButton to login in FB inside layout that It´s inflate in my DialogFragment:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/login_shareButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
```

After user´s log I handle the action of LoginButton with:

```
share = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              publishFeedDialog();
            }
       });
```

Then when I push this button can pop up the login window or the feeddialog.

So... my problem is when my app has opened the DialogFragment and the Login/DialogFeed and I rotate my device (handling manually in onConfigurationChanged()) and refresh the DialogFragment to landscape version, then the Login/DialogFeed hides behind the DialogFragment

resume: - Main activity calls DialogFragment
        --> DialogFramgent calls Login or FeedDialog (if user is login or not before)
        --> Rotate the device and refresh DialogFragment to Landscape version
        --> Login/FeedDialog is hidden and my app show my DialogFragment
        --> I can only close the DialogFragment to access Login/FeedDialog
        --> If I close it, and I try use the Login/DialogFeed --> error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1362): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DialogImage{4170ad00} not attached to Activity
```

Comment: Are you referring to login (using the LoginActivity), or the "Feed Dialog"? Can you include more code on how you're doing the login?

Comment: I´m using a LoginButton inside my DialogFragment to login. I edit and add more code, thanks ^^

Comment: Added, sorry for my english, I hope it's comprehensible